# SQL Union all Null as in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

in Microsoft SQL, when UNION ALL, if the second table doesn't have table1's column, I can use NULL AS.

Sample code:

```
select a.Key, a.amount from tableA a 
UNION ALL
select b.key, NULL AS 'amount' from tableB b
```

but how to the same NULL AS in Amazon Redshift SQL?

I have a syntax error at or near "'amount'"

Comment: You have an odd quote character after `amount`. What happens when you try this? What isn't working?

Comment: @Phil redshift said "syntax error at or near "'amount'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use single quotes for column aliases.

The following should work in almost any database (although `key` may need to be escaped):

```
select a.Key, a.amount from tableA a 
union all
select b.key, NULL AS amount from tableB b;
```

In fact, the alias is unnecessary in the second query, so you can write:

```
select a.Key, a.amount from tableA a 
union all
select b.key, NULL from tableB b;
```